# Почему не работает код? В чем ошибка?

Tags: javascript

```js
var El = document.getEmelentById('hider');
El.addEventListener('click', delete);

function delete() {
 document.getElementById('text').textContent = '';

}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="hider" value="Нажмите, чтобы спрятать текст"   />

<div id="text">Текст</div>
```

Выдает ошибку:

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got ')'

Comment: потому что [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) это встроенный оператор, и его нельзя использовать в качестве имени функции/переменной/...

Comment: Спасибо, про ошибку в синтаксисе можно не писать, я сам заметил :)

Answer (score 0):

Не

> getEmelentById

а

> getElementById

```js
var El = document.getElementById('hider');
El.addEventListener('click', del);

function del() {
 document.getElementById('text').textContent = '';

}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="hider" value="Нажмите, чтобы спрятать текст"   />

<div id="text">Текст</div>
```